# Reflection to get public instance properties in UWP

Tags: c#, silverlight, reflection, uwp

I am porting a Silverlight application to UWP.
In my Silverlight app, i get the public instance properties:

```
Type t;
t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

In UWP it look like the GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public) method is no longer available. Is there another way to accomplish this in UWP?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo.declaredproperties(v=vs.110).aspx) source, you can do the following:

```
var props = t.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties
                           .Where(x => x.GetMethod.IsPublic);
```

Comment: thank you user3185569. How to specify binding flas to get non-public or non-static properties ? foreach (PropertyInfo p in props )
            {
                if (p.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsPublic
                    || p.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsNotPublic ))
                    || p.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsInstance)//????
                {
                   //....
                }
            }

Comment: @sarahberderian Have you added `using System.Reflection;` because I can use `GetProperties` with Binding Flags in my UWP project.

Comment: @sarahberderian However, check the updated answer for how to get properties with public getter, if you want to include ones with publice setters only, add `|| x.SetMethod.IsPublic`

Comment: thank you user3185569 for your help. when i create a new uwp library project, i can see t.GetProperties with Binding Flags. However when changed the target of my original silverlight 8.1 project to unuversal windows 10, i can not see t.GetProperties!.

Comment: That will only return declared properties.