# Can't retrieve dependency properties in uwp with reflection

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to get all dependency properties of a control. I tried something like:

```
static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetDependencyProperties(this Type type)
{
    var dependencyProperties = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                                   .Where(p => p.FieldType.Equals(typeof(DependencyProperty)));
            return dependencyProperties;
}

public static IEnumerable<BindingExpression> GetBindingExpressions(this FrameworkElement element)
{
    IEnumerable<FieldInfo> infos = element.GetType().GetDependencyProperties();

    foreach (FieldInfo field in infos)
    {
        if (field.FieldType == typeof(DependencyProperty))
        {
            DependencyProperty dp = (DependencyProperty)field.GetValue(null);
            BindingExpression ex = element.GetBindingExpression(dp);

            if (ex != null)
            {
                yield return ex;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Binding found with path: “ +ex.ParentBinding.Path.Path");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also a similar stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837778/reflection-to-get-public-instance-properties-in-uwp). The `GetFields` method always returns an empty enumeration.

[EDIT] I executed the following lines in the universal windows platform project

```
typeof(CheckBox).GetFields()    {System.Reflection.FieldInfo[0]}
typeof(CheckBox).GetProperties()    {System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[98]}
typeof(CheckBox).GetMembers()   {System.Reflection.MemberInfo[447]}
```

Seems to be a bug?

Comment: GetFields works for me, but of course only returns those DependencyProperty fields declared in `type`, not in any base classes. Besides that, it looks dubious that you use both `p.FieldType.Equals(typeof(DependencyProperty))` and `field.FieldType == typeof(DependencyProperty)`. Better write `typeof(DependencyProperty).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType))`.

Comment: When I'm in the debugger, and I execute typeof(ListBox).GetFields() I get an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP, the static DependencyProperty members seem to be defined as public static properties instead of public static fields. See for example the [`SelectionModeProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listbox.selectionmodeproperty) property, which is declared as

```
public static DependencyProperty SelectionModeProperty { get; }
```

So while the expression

```
typeof(ListBox).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(f => typeof(DependencyProperty).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType))
```

returns an empty IEnumerable, the expression

```
typeof(ListBox).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(p => typeof(DependencyProperty).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
```

returns an IEnumerable with one element, namely the SelectionModeProperty mentioned above.

Note that you would also have to investigate all base classes to get a complete list of DependencyProperty fields/properties.